# How to compute how much of my buffer is used (size) for write()?

Tags: c

```
char buf[256];
sprintf(buf, "It was %s\r\n", weather);
write(p->fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

The code above is a snippet of a large project.

`buf` is used to hold a number of different strings of different length. How do I know what to put in the write function? `sizeof()` just gives `256` I believe, because write just spits out a bunch of extra garbage characters.

Comment: Did you read the documentation on [sprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)?

Comment: maybe you want `strlen()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the code using `len` should be:

```
char buf[256];
int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "It was %s\r\n", weather);

if ( len < 0 || len >= sizeof buf )
     // error handling, abort...

write(p->fd, buf, len);
```

Using `sprintf` is risky as it may cause a buffer overflow if `weather` is not fully under your control.

As mentioned in its documentation, the `sprintf` family can return a negative value if there is an error; and the returned value can be larger than the buffer size if the write would have not fitted in the buffer.

Another option covered by other answers is to omit checking `len`, and instead use `strlen` to find the length to send.  Some would consider that unnecessarily inefficient. Further, in that case you should really check `len` anyway in case [encoding fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948361/when-and-why-can-sprintf-fail/) which would result in `strlen` operating on garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is a combination of memset and strlen or sprintf return

```
char buf[256];
memset(buf,'\0',sizeof(buf));
sprintf(buf, "It was %s\r\n", weather);
write(p->fd, buf, strlen(buf));
```

OR

```
char buf[256];
    memset(buf,'\0',sizeof(buf));
    int len = sprintf(buf, "It was %s\r\n", weather);
    write(p->fd, buf, len);
```

Comment: I saw that on tutorialspoint.com but I didn't understand why I needed `memset`.

Comment: Because when you declare an array, all the indexes of arrays contain garbage values. And you don't want garbage values to effect you functionality. For example for strings, they must end on '\0' character in order to strlen() to work correctly. But if you don't do memset, the end point will contain some garbage character and strlen() will give you wrong result

Comment: The `memset` is useful in the `strlen` version in case `sprintf` [fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948361/when-and-why-can-sprintf-fail/). This is so that `strlen` finds `0` instead of trying to read an uninitialized buffer. However you only need to set `buf[0] = 0;`, not the whole thing.

Comment: @Yasir Majeed "if you don't do memset, the end point will contain some garbage " is not correct.  `sprintf()` will append the needed `'\0'`.  Check the return value of `sprintf()` to detect failure.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `sizeof()` does not do what you want.

How you determine how much valid data is actually in your buffer depends on how you put the data there.  In your particular case, you could either use the return value of `sprintf()`, or you could use `strlen()` on the buffer.  I would recommend the former, since `sprintf()` is going to return that value whether you use it or not.  Either of those alternatives will exclude the string's trailing null byte, so be sure to add one to the length if you want to write that null, too.

If elsewhere you are filling the buffer by other means, then the appropriate mechanism for determining how many bytes to write may differ.