# What are the possible reasons of vsnprintf fails? Cannot access errno (postmortem)

Tags: c, printf, shared-libraries, arm64

I have some segfault in my application and what I've seen happening is that "vsnprintf" always fails(it returns negative number, in my case "-1").

This is on aarch64 (arm64).

The segfault is because of some bad implementation in a third party library but I want to know what are the possible reasons of vsnprintf failing.
Also, is there a way to see errno or the reason of vsnprintf fail with GDB in a core dump? I don't have the process running.

This is the relevant implementation:

```
int mg_printf(const char *fmt, ...) {
  int len;
  char mem[100];
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  len = vsnprintf(mem, sizeof(mem), fmt, ap); // this fails all the time
  va_end(ap);
  return len;
}

// len is very sketchy
int len = 1602988490;
const char* pr = "[aaaa:bbbb:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010]:12345";
mg_printf("Host: %.*s\r\n", len, pr);
```

So, as you can see, the "len" provided to vsnprintf in the va_list is very "sketchy". Can this be the reason of the fail? This "len" value is not intended but it's the result of some other calls.

Comment: Why do you think it fails? It looks ok to me. https://godbolt.org/z/KdYaM1188

Comment: Where do you get that number for `len`? Do you have a breakpoint in `mg_printf`? Also it is assigned the value that is returned from `vsnprintf` which you claim always is `-1`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo this is just a very reduced snipped of the full code. I already tried this on godbolt and I know it works. Also, this code is on arm64.

Comment: @w0wy We can't help if we don't see code that reproduces the error you get. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @Gerhardh it is code in third party library (mongoose) and it is because of some pointer arithmetic(const char* - const char*).
Related to the other mentions: I'm only able to do postmortem debugging with core dumps(so, no breakpoints). If I had possibility to debug live, it would've been much easier.
I'm mostly curious why could vsnprintf fail.

Comment: @TedLyngmo understood and I agree. To be honest, if I could reproduce it, I would've probably found the issue also.
My main question in this case would be: why could vsnprintf fail? Is there some "usual" failure that can happen? Something standard?

Comment: *The segfault is because of some bad implementation in a third party library.* Do you have proof of that? It is almost always the case that the fault is in one's own code, but has not yet been identified.

Comment: If the real code has invalid conversion specifiers and/or non-matching arguments, sure, it could crash

Comment: specing `1602988490` as a width specifier for outputting `"[aaaa:bbbb:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010]:12345"` seems excessive.  Can you fill in any more details regarding:  _"This "len" value is not intended but it's the result of some other calls"_ ??

Comment: Is it possible that it is being fed a buffer containing multibyte or wide characters?  [from question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948361/when-and-why-can-sprintf-fail)

Comment: @WeatherVane yes. Here is what I meant: https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/6.11/mongoose.c at line 2031, len is -1 and it crashes.
This happens because vsnprintf fails everytime and eventually, the malloc will fail since size of it is always doubled in the while loop.
Free buffer -> try malloc double size -> if success try vsnprintf again -> if not success set len to -1 -> access buffer[-1].

Comment: @ryyker yes. It happens here: https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/6.11/mongoose.c at line 10184.
path.p is NULL (0x0) and host.p is [aaaa:bbbb:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0010]:12345.
These are both const char*.

Comment: `len` is not `-1` at line 2031 `(*buf)[len] = 0;`. It was `< 0` at the start of the code block, but at line 2012 `while (len < 0)` ensures that it is not.

Comment: @WeatherVane no. This is only as long as malloc succeeds everytime. If malloc fails, len will be -1. Lines 2019 and 2020.
If size is doubled continuously, malloc is bound to fail. Afaik, it can only alloc up to 2GB at a time.
Max value of size_t(unsigned int) is higher than 2GB(in bytes).

Comment: You seem to be right.

Answer (score 2):

> So, as you can see, the "len" provided to vsnprintf in the va_list is very "sketchy". Can this be the reason of the fail? This "len" value is not intended but it's the result of some other calls.

Yes.

`printf()` and friends are subject to an environmental limitation.

> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095.  C17dr § 7.21.6.1 15

Any conversion above 4095 risks problems.  Limit `len`.

```
// mg_printf("Host: %.*s\r\n", len, pr);
mg_printf("Host: %.*s\r\n", len > 4000 ? 4000 : len, pr);
```

Or perhaps user code (that does not use `*printf()`) to print the string with a huge 1602988490 limit.

```
mg_printf("Host: ");

for (int i = 0; i < len && pr[i]; i++) putchar(pr[i]);

mg_printf("\r\n");
```

---

> Also, is there a way to see errno or the reason of vsnprintf ...

In general, `vsnprintf()` is not specified to set `errno` on any condition.  Select implementations may do so though.